# Joining two KeyedTuple objects in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following two queries:

```
res=session.query(t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl).filter(
    t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl.c.mailing_id==mid)

res_t=session.query(t_marketing_time_stat_tbl).filter(
    t_marketing_time_stat_tbl.c.mailing_id==mid)

try:
    return res.one() + res_t.one()
except NoResultFound as e:
    return None
```

`res` and `res_t` are both of type `sqlalchemy.util._collections.KeyedTuple` which support addition, however, the resulting object is a simple tuple, without keys.

I would like to have a combined result, so I did the following:

```
rv = {}
res=session.query(t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl).filter(
    t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl.c.mailing_id==mid)

res_t=session.query(t_marketing_time_stat_tbl).filter(
    t_marketing_time_stat_tbl.c.mailing_id==mid)

try:
    res =res.one()
    res_t = res_t.one()
    for k in res.keys():
        rv[k] = getattr(res, k)
    for k in res_t.keys():
        rv[k] = getattr(res_t, k)
except NoResultFound as e:
    return None
```

While this works, I suspect there is a built-in way, or a better way of achieving this with SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic problem is you want to combine...erm, join... similar data from your database. There are a couple different angles we can take to solve this problem:

1. We could do as you are, but a more simple way.
2. We can let the database do the work.

The second way is the preferred solution. Databases are *designed* to solve this problem and they solve them very efficiently. They are meant to be a powerful tool to store, update, and eventually relate data.

---

If you are set on the first solution, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-can-i-merge-union-two-python-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) describes several ways to combine two `dicts`. Combine any one of those solutions with the [`KeyedTuple._asdict`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html?highlight=keyedtuple#sqlalchemy.util.KeyedTuple._asdict) function can simplify your code:

```
try:
    # In Python 3, you cannot use the + operator. You can use the | operator instead.
    joined_result = dict(res.one()._asdict().items() + res_t.one()._asdict().items())
except NoResultFound:
    return None
```

---

Now, the preferred solution would be to use a JOIN to combine the two queries into one. SQLAlchemy's [`join` documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.join) has a quite a few examples of how `join` can be used. The basic example should suffice for your purposes:

```
joined_result = session.query(t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl)\
                       .join(t_marketing_time_stat_tbl)\
                       .filter(t_marketing_mailing_stats_tbl.c.mailing_id==mid)

try:
    return joined_result.one()
except NoResultFound:
    return None
```

---

To wrap up, I have a few style comments:

1. Be consistent with your spacing. For the most part you have a single space before and after operators. [This is good](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#other-recommendations). However, in a few locations, you have one or both of the spaces missing.
2. Don't truncate words in variable names (unless they are **very** long). Typical Python convention tries to be more verbose than brief. Thus the variable name `res` would better named as `result`.

   Also, make sure that your names are unambiguous: what does `res_t` do different than `res`? What does the prefix `t_` mean in your table names mean? Given the context, `t_` could easily mean 'table'; however, wouldn't the suffix `_tbl` then be redundant?